# Weird animated on pushing controller hiding tab bar and adding a toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have an app with the hierarchy of `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UIViewController`. Currently if you tap on the `collectionView`'s cells it performs a segue to show the full size image. I have the view controller that is being pushed setting the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to `YES`. Then in `viewWillAppear:` on the view controller being pushed, I am calling `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO]` and as you can see in the animated below the bottom left of the screen is present from the previous screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change ur code to this: Set animated YES.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I had to have the view controller being pushed go under the bottom bar otherwise it gave the weird animation. When I did that everything went back to normal. I then also animated the call to `setToolbaHidden:animated:` as suggested above.